# How can I set "disable_http" which is flag parameter with file strategy in marathon

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'am trying to add the file /etc/marathon/conf/disable_http with no value but I have this error:

```
Error: Bad arguments for option 'disable_http': '' - too many arguments for flag option
```

I try, empty file, "enabled" value, "disabled" value, "true".
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using the package provide by mesoshepere the file must start with a ? , with this the content of the file is not add to the command line

https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/22a00d46fa1741e5c237f2e70e4180d53b3b127b/bin/marathon-framework#L42